# Will big 4 tell next employer I was put on pip

Tags: career-development, hiring-process, performance, disability, dismissal

Long story short, I underperformed at work and failed a bunch of exams
Employed for 6 months
Grad scheme
Invited to a capability meeting
If I am put on PIP, will my next employer find out I was on PIP?
Based on the UK

Comment: No, the potential employers won't know about your PIP. Even if you are fired, most old companies won't tell your potential employers the reasons you are no longer with the old companies. They will only tell the potential companies about your job title, and start and end dates with the old companies.

Comment: You tagged this [disability], what does a disability have to do with it?

Comment: Not in the US.  Typically all they say is if you were eligible for rehire or not and confirm the dates you were employed.

Comment: @Job_September_2020   Your comment is definitely the correct answer for the UK.

Answer (score 5):

Unknowable.

It's unlikely that they would put it directly in a reference as this is (most likely) a violations of privacy or confidentiality laws and would be a minor legal exposure risk. See for example: https://www.refapp.com/blog/unveiling-the-legal-landscape-of-reference-checking-answers-to-common-questions

It's however possible that it would show up "in code" in the reference especially if the prospective employer asks about it.

There is always the "unofficial" path as well. The hiring managers knows someone who knows someone and the topic my come up at a casual phone call or when going out of for after work beers in a pub.

Answer (score 2):

In the USA putting anything in the reference other than “X worked here from this date to that date” puts the company at risk of getting sued. Maybe not successfully, but being sued is always a cost they want to avoid. If you were fired for raping another employee and there is evidence of that, then it is very likely that this goes into your reference.

In other countries the chances of being sued are usually less, but it’s still a risk.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning on failing the PIP, may I submit that worrying about outcomes you can't control isn't really useful.

The alternative is you take control of the situation and  survive the PIP, or fix your problems before the PIP starts. Or voluntarily resign before failing the PIP.

See past answers about PIPs.